# How to simplify O(2^(logN)) to O(N)

Tags: runtime, time-complexity

In Cracking the Coding Interview there's an example where the runtime for a recursive algorithm that counts the nodes in a binary search tree is O(2^(logN)). The book explains how we simplify to get O(N) like so...

```
2^p = Q 
logQ = P 
Let P = 2^(logN).
```

but I am lost at the step when they say Let P = 2^(logN). I don't understand how we know to set those two equal to one another, and I also don't understand this next step... (Although they tell me they do it by the definition of log base 2)

```
logP = logN 
P = N 
2^(logN) = N
```

Therefore the runtime of the code is O(N)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The definition of logarithm is “to what power does the base need to be raised to get this value” so if the base of the logarithm is 2, then raising 2 to that power brings us to the original value.

Example: N is 256. If we take the base 2 log of it we get 8. If we raise 2 to the power of 8 we get 256. So it is linear and we can make it to be just N.

If the log would be in a different base, for example 10, the conversion would just require dividing the exponent with a constant, making the more accurate form into `N = 2^(log N / log 2)`, which can be changed into `N / 2^(1 / log 2) = 2^log N`. Here the divider for N on the left is a constant so we can forget it when discussing complexity and again come to `N = 2^log N`.

You can also test it by hand. Log2 of 256 is 8. Log2 of 128 is 7. 8/7 is about 1.14. Log10 of 256 is 2.4. Log10 of 128 is 2.1. 2.4/2.1 is about 1.14. So the base doesn’t matter, the value you get out isn’t the same but it is linear. So mathematically N doesn’t equal to 2^Log10 N, but in complexity terms it does.

Comment: Isn't `log N / log 2` equal to `log(N^(1 / (log 2))`? This would make the result a different power-law of N, not just a constant factor times N?

Comment: Thanks! Your examples help me understand it.

Comment: @JessicaWang Welcome to StackOverflow! The conventional way to thank here is to accept an answer.

Answer (score 4):

*<sup>Assuming logN is log<sub>2</sub>N</sup>*

This line:

```
Let P = 2^(logN).
```

Just assumes that `P` equals to `2^(logN)`. You do not know N yet, you just define how `P` and `N` relates to each other.

Later, you can apply `log` function to both sides of equation. And since `log(2^(logN))` is `logN`, the next step is:

```
logP = logN
```

And, obviously, when `logP = logN`, then:

```
P = N
```

And previously you assumed that `P = 2^(logN)`, then:

```
2^(logN) = N
```

Moreover, all of this could be simplified to `2^logN = N` by definition of the `log` function.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not the best at math so I get quite confused.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the original question probably implicitly assumed that the logarithm was supposed to be in base 2, so that 2^(log_2(N)) is just N, by definition of log_2(x) as the inverse function of 2^y.

However, it's interesting to examine this a bit more carefully if the logarithm is to a different base. Standard results allow us to write the logarithm to base `b` as follows:

[image]

where `ln(x)` is the natural logarithm (using base `e`). Similarly, one can rewrite `2^x` as follows:

[image]

We can then rewrite the original order-expression as follows:

[image]

which can be reduced to:

[image]

So, if the base `b` of our logarithm is 2, then this is clearly just `N`. However, if the base is different, then we get `N` raised to a power. For example, if `b=10` we get N raised to the power 0.301, which is definitely a more slowly increasing function than `O(N)`.

We can check this directly with the following Python script:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = numpy.arange(1, 100)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(N, 2**(numpy.log2(N)))
plt.xlabel('N')
plt.ylabel(r'$2^{\log_2 N}$')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(N, 2**(numpy.log10(N)))
plt.xlabel('N')
plt.ylabel(r'$2^{\log_{10} N}$')

plt.show()
```

The graph this produces when we assume that the logarithm is to base two:

[image]

is very different from the graph when the logarithm is taken to base ten:

[image]